# Stored Procedure in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am a first timer in using `phpmyadmin`. I am not aware in my stored procedure that I am working in my code. I don't know how to make a stored procedure in `phpmyadmin`.

This is my code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_1_service_card_report(IN service_card_no INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE error_1 INT;

    SELECT  COUNT(service_card.customer_id)
    INTO    error_1 
    FROM    service_card
    WHERE   service_card.id =  27;

    DECLARE error_2 INT;

    SELECT  COUNT(service_card.serial_no_id)
    INTO    error_2 
    FROM    service_card
    WHERE   service_card.id =  27;

    IF error_1 > 0 AND error_2 > 0 THEN
     SELECT
       service_card.id as yes from service_card where service_card.id=27;
    ELSE
      SELECT service_card.customer_id as no from service_card.id=27;
    END IF ;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is my error:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE error_2 INT;
>
> SELECT  COUNT(service_card.serial_no_id)
>   INTO  ' at line 11

Can you guys help me with this? I spent my 1 hour searching answers also here on stackoverflow.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why u got this error but did u tried to move that line to just below error_1 declare line?

Comment: Try moving the second DECLARE to immediately after the first.

Comment: I just put the eror_2 in the top. I just got red x spot in because of the comma(;)" I just cannot understand what I did wrong.

Comment: The select in the else needs a where statement.

Answer (score 0):

`DECLARE` statements must be placed at first and you have a `select` typo in query at end of your procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_1_service_card_report(IN service_card_no INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE error_1 INT;
    DECLARE error_2 INT;

    SELECT  COUNT(service_card.customer_id)
    INTO    error_1 
    FROM    service_card
    WHERE   service_card.id =  27;


    SELECT  COUNT(service_card.serial_no_id)
    INTO    error_2 
    FROM    service_card
    WHERE   service_card.id =  27;

    IF error_1 > 0 AND error_2 > 0 THEN
     SELECT
       service_card.id as yes from service_card where service_card.id=27;
    ELSE
      SELECT service_card.customer_id as no from service_card where service_card.id=27;
    END IF ;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```